# Groups differ from the local ones when logging in remotely

Tags: ssh, group, authentication, pam, ldap

We store our users in LDAP, alongside some groups that have meaning across different systems (organizational roles including `wheel`). There are also groups local to workstations, e.g. `audio` or `video` that are not desirable to be put into LDAP. Now if I log in locally I get those local groups, but if I log in via SSH into the same machine I lack them. They of course come back, if I use `su` straight afterwards. I may be on the wrong track, but suspect PAM.

Relevant entries from `nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:      compat ldap
shadow:      compat ldap
group:       compat ldap
```

As for pam, always the auth line, but the other lines are the same

`/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
auth            include         system-remote-login
```

`/etc/pam.d/system-remote-login` (identical to `system-local-login` I might add)

```
auth            include         system-login
```

`/etc/pam.d/system-login`

```
auth            required        pam_tally2.so onerr=succeed
auth            required        pam_shells.so 
auth            required        pam_nologin.so 
auth            include         system-auth
auth            optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so

account         required        pam_access.so 
account         required        pam_nologin.so 
account         include         system-auth
account         required        pam_tally2.so onerr=succeed 

password        include         system-auth
password        optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so

session         optional        pam_loginuid.so
session         required        pam_env.so 
session         optional        pam_lastlog.so 
session         include         system-auth
session         optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session         optional        pam_motd.so motd=/etc/motd
session         optional        pam_mail.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/su`

```
auth       sufficient   pam_rootok.so
auth       required     pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth       include              system-auth

account    include              system-auth

password   include              system-auth

session    include              system-auth
session    required     pam_env.so
session    optional             pam_xauth.so
```

/etc/pam.d/common-auth:

```
auth    required     pam_group.so use_first_pass
```

What could be the problem and how would I solve it? I'm happy to provide other information needed.

Comment: What does your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` looks like for `group`? What is the output of `getent YOURUSERNAME`? Does your `/etc/pam.d/sshd` @include common-{session,auth,password,account}?

Comment: which process/steps you setup at client end ?

Comment: I need to add a database for getent's commandline, which one should i query?
@RahulPatil What do you mean exactly? What is the client to you? The machine connecting via ssh?

Comment: Query the group database (`getent group USER`)

Comment: @Max do you want same groups via `ssh` login same as when you access via  `su`. am i correct ?

Comment: `getent group max` is empty, but that makes sense, this I don't have a group named after my user that I am part of and that command would query a group named max, right?
@RahulPatil yes

Comment: @Max , sorry this is last question , if possible post your `/etc/pam.d/su`

Comment: Added that as well.

Comment: What's the operating system? And variant/distribution thereof?

Comment: Gentoo on the client, Debian on the server (ldap)

Comment: Just to check: do you have `UsePAM yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Comment: Yes i do have that.

Comment: It is strange to me pam_ldap.so it not in any files, like "type     sufficient      pam_ldap.so". Also, "su" config uses " pam_xauth.so", where "ssh" config doesn't. Could you indicate which distro you are using? Pam packaging may vary.

Comment: @Aurelien, when you have "shadow ldap", then pam_unix does the authentication retrieving the password info from nss.

Comment: I think you're off track suspecting PAM. More likely a NIS problem. PAM has no idea of groups at all; it's all done through libc when sshd calls initgroups.

Comment: Actually, I slightly modify that: apparently some modules hook the pam_setcred call to establish user groups, which is why sshd calls initgroups _before_ pam_setcred. Hmmm.

Comment: Did vonbrand's answer help?

Comment: Not really to be honest. It's all true (apart from the fact that i checked that the uids and users always coincide) but doesn't really get me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took heart today and finally solved it. The pam chain works like this

- `/etc/pam.d/sshd` includes:

  - `/etc/pam.d/system-remote-login` that includes:

    - `/etc/pam.d/system-login` that includes:

      - `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` which has an optional requirement

Apparently the last include does not work for some reason. The reason why I was so puzzled so far was that I trusted that these includes would work, which wasn't the case. If someone can explain why I'd be very grateful. I know this because if i add the line

```
auth    optional  pam_group.so
```

into the `/etc/pam.d/system-login` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

The login program (which sets up your environment, including UID, GID and supplemental groups) gets data on username <--> UID, GID and the supplementary groups to which username belongs, from some sort of database. Traditionally from the /etc/passwd and /etc/groups files, today also from LDAP. Depending on the data source, the groups you get assigned can vary.

Be careful, if different sources are mixed you can very well end up with an account with the same name but different UIDs (the system really uses UID internally), or different sets of groups. The result is normally *very* entertaining for the casual onlooker, while leading to premature baldness due to extensive hair-pulling for the parties in charge. (Been there.)

Answer (score 0):

Into `nsswitch.conf`:

```
    group:          compat ldap
```

afaik this calls getgrent, which gets the groups (group entries)

EDIT: another thing is to add the following to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth    required     pam_group.so use_first_pass
```

for more information have a look here: [Assign local groups to users](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication#Assign_local_groups_to_users) and maybe this [newgrp-and-groups-assigned-via-pam-group-so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15366/newgrp-and-groups-assigned-via-pam-group-so?rq=1)

Comment: That line is already present just like that.

Comment: maybe add it to "Relevant entries from nsswitch.conf" in your question.

Comment: done and the edit didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: did you do `pam-auth-update` and a nscd restart?

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost similar problem: when logged in using ssh, some groups were missing. It has been solved by changing /etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
group:      compat  -> group:      files nis
```