# Why is my user in different groups when logged in via SSH and on the desktop?

Tags: ssh, sudo, group, vnc

I am running CentOS 7.3. If I log in over SSH I can run `sudo` commands and if I run `groups` I can see I'm in the groups `<username>` and `wheel`.

If I connect to the desktop over VNC and launch a terminal, I can't run sudo commands ("username is not in the sudoers file") and the only group I'm in is `<username>`.

Why the difference, and how do I fix it to run sudo on the desktop?

After questions in the comments; this is a standard build on a physical (Dell I think) server. There is no ldap process running but I have asked the question of the guy who installed it.

From SSH terminal:

```
uid=1001(username) gid=1001(username) groups=1001(username),10(wheel)
```

From desktop terminal:

```
uid=1001(username) gid=1001(username) groups=1001(username)
```

If I run `su - username` in the desktop terminal I do then get the correct groups.

Further update: Definitely no ldap in use.

Comment: Are you the same user? With the same user ID (not name, numeric ID)? What kind of setup is this? Is there any user administration system like LDAP in place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groups differ from the local ones when logging in remotely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60285/groups-differ-from-the-local-ones-when-logging-in-remotely)

Comment: @terdon yes, same user. Same UID, same GID. No LDAP. Fairly standard install on a physical server.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I just had a quick look at the linked question. I notice that OP got his groups back by running su - user in the terminal. Just tried that and I get the same thing. I will look at that question more in depth. Cheers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `id` from each of the two ways you use to log in. If you don't use LDAP, the question @ThomasDickey suggested is unlikely to be relevant. Are you really really sure there's no LDAP?

Comment: @terdon 99% sure. Question updated. Thanks.

Comment: Dear people who are VTC. This is not a dupe as we are not using ldap here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to relogin, i.e. restart your desktop session (not to reconnect to the VNC server) for the newly added groups to appear. Alternatively, you can use `newgrp` to get into the `wheel` group in each of your terminals w/o using `su`.

Comment: Ah, excellent point. I hadn’t considered this as it’s all been set up by someone else. Will give it a try.